# OS X 10.8.6 installed on USB Flash Drive using most of drive space

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb

I have created an installation of OS X on a small drive. Everything has worked fine apart from the fact that it has used up most of my space. According the file size on each of the folders in the root directory do not amount to the space shown in the disk utility.

I have only done an install of OS X and DeployStudio so it surely should not be using up an entire 32 GB drive.

I have tried verifying and repairing the disk as well as a couple of reboots.

Comment: Regardless of your current issue, this doesn't seem like a good idea to me unless your drive is an actual SSD instead of a run-of-the-mill USB Flash stick.  I would not expect a USB Flash stick to be able to handle the write load of an operating system reliably.

Comment: I am not concerned with performance at present. It is just to prove that it works. I will then move it to a larger faster drive. I have found that using the OSX System Information->Storage, tool that 'Other' was using a lot of space. Using Disk Daisy I figured out directorys After removing the sleep image files and some other updates files this gave me the space I needed :) just in case anyone else has the need to do this in future. 

Note: I am aware this is a bad idea to remove your sleep image, but for my purposes it was necessary. I would not recommend doing it unless you need to.

Comment: It's not performance I'm speaking of, but rather that you will likely wear out the drive prematurely.  But if you're just playing with it briefly, you'll probably be fine.  As far as your solution, I recommend you post it as an answer to your own question and accept it.  Maybe reword the question a bit to indicate this isn't specific to USB Flash drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zigg has mentioned this isnt a great idea for a long term solution. However if you do want to do this for any sort of drive it can be done using Daisy Disk app to remove any sleep image files. However these will be recreated when your machine goes into sleep mode again.